# Swift - setting different row height for different cells in one table

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table with two type of cells. First type of cell is used as heading and second type is actual content. I setup different row identifiers for cells and I want heading cell to have more height than cell with content. I defined cell height in atributes inspector for heading cell but it does not help

I also tried this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 100
    } else {

    return 30

    }
}
```

but it sets height 100 to the first cell of content cell, but needed cell with heading that is actually at index 0 is not affected

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be defining a separate header view for the tableview at either the tableview or for the section. You can set the automatic dimension for the tableview cell or create a custom tableview (in storyboard or code). You haven't stated your requirements very well however, you really should start by reading through the basic concepts in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/).